# How I can sort woocommerce all products by category

Tags: sorting, woocommerce, product, wordpress

I have wp_query request for give all products, and needs to sort this for 2 fields:
by category & by menu_order.
Various! I need to sort by "menu_order" in each category.

In simple query:

```
$args = array(
        'orderby' =. 'product_cat menu_order'
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        );

      $loop = new WP_Query($args);
```

In global $product, exist field "menu_order", but not exist field "product_cat".

Can I do it with wp_query? Or maybe exist another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I was founded right way to do it, code bellow, this example for

```
/* Products Loop */
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => $prod_per_page,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'product_cat' => $product_cat,
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' => $subcats_ar,
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                ),
            ),
            'orderby' => array('menu_order' => 'ASC', 'title' => 'ASC')
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query($args);
```

More simple way, without pagination and exclude sub categories:

```
 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'product_cat' => $product_cat,
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'term_id'
                ),
            ),
            'orderby' => array('menu_order' => 'ASC', 'title' => 'ASC')
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query($args);
```

Magic line for this is:

```
'orderby' => array('menu_order' => 'ASC', 'title' => 'ASC')
```

Comment: This will just order by the menu_order and not the categories.

Answer (score -1):

While trying out and search i found a solution to it to use two queries to achieve this purpose the below example might help you achieve your purpose.

`<?php`

`$catargs = array(`

```
'orderby'                  => 'name',

'order'                    => 'ASC',
```

`);`

`$categories = get_categories( $catargs );`

`foreach ($categories as $category) {?>`

`<h3><?php echo $category->name;
// Category title ?></h3>
<?php`

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (

    'post_type'              => 'resources',

    'cat'                    => $category->cat_ID,

    'posts_per_page'         => '-1',

    'order'                  => 'ASC',

'orderby'                => 'title',

);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

`// The Loop`

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        ?>
        <h5><?php the_title(); // Post title ?></h5>
        <?php 
        // You can all phone/ email here
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

`}
?>`

Let me know if the method worked for you.